# Static block category pages with form causing page load issues

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, forms, contact-us

I'm not even sure how to word this.

I have a category pointing to a static block. Within the static block I have my content which includes a contact form:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Every-time I load one of these pages the form is acting as an anchor link and I'm brought directly to the form, skipping any content above it.

Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: Just to add. In my form.phtml the form has an id="contactForm" which is causing the issue, if I remove it, I no longer get the issue. What would be causing this and is the ID required to submit the form?

Comment: Do you have #contactForm appended to your url?  If not, then perhaps providing a link to a page that exhibits this behavior would help us nail it down.

Comment: @TJGambleatJamersan It's not appended to the end of the url. I removed the ID from the form and it works just fine. I'm just concerned that the form will no longer submit.

Comment: Well, the only way to answer that is testing.  In theory, a form doesn't need an ID to submit, but who knows what javascript is acting on it.   Again, a link to the page may help (with the scroll down issue) if you can provide it.